# How can i add a css class only to the h3 tag clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Softshell</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Option</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Option 1</h3></a></div>
</li>
```

I need to show which one `h3` tag is clicked to show active

Comment: Show us what you have done till now. Can you copy your current jQuery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lineop1 a h3').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // to prevent page refresh with new url
      $('h3').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from other h3 tag
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to current clicked tag
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Softshell</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Option</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="lineop1"><a href="php/fabric/process1.php"><h3>Option 1</h3></a></div>
</li>
```

***Note:-*** `id` need to be unique per element. so convert `id` to `class` around  `<div's>`

***And if you want that after click on `h3` when page refresh, then also the corresponding `h3` tag have the active class, then you have to use `localstorage` concept like below:-***

jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').eq( localStorage.parent ).find('h3').addClass('active');
    $('.lineop1 a h3').click(function(e){
        var pagename = $(location).attr("href").split('/').pop();
        localStorage.parent=$(this).closest('li').index();
    });
});
```

Html:-

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <div class="lineop1"><a href="process1.php"><h3>Softshell</h3></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="lineop1"><a href="process1.php"><h3>Option</h3></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="lineop1"><a href="process1.php"><h3>Option 1</h3></a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tested it on localhost at my end and working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

add a click handler to `h3`. Add class `active` to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','h3',function(){
        $('h3').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
   color:#ff00eb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="#"><h3>Softshell</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="#"><h3>Option</h3></a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div id="lineop1"><a href="#"><h3>Option 1</h3></a></div>
</li>
```

**Edit**: its always good practice to attach click event to the closest unique parent element. so I have included `$(document).On`.

Follow this link to see working of [Direct Vs Deletegated Events](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/04/direct-vs-delegated-events-with-jquery-on-method.html)